# using CASE statement in postgresql

Tags: ruby, postgresql

```
select *,'example' AS species 
from top_half 
inner join bottom_half 
on top_half.id = bottom_half.id 
order by species(
    CASE
       WHEN heads > arms THEN species.example = 'beast'
       when  tails > legs then species.example = 'beast'
       else species.example = 'weirdo'
    END
);
```

I am getting the following errors :

There was an error with the SQL query:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "species" LINE 2:     WHEN heads > arms THEN species.example = 'beast'
>   There was an error with the SQL query:
>
> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "species" LINE 2:     WHEN heads > arms THEN species.example = 'beast'

how to solve this ?

---

[codewars.com/kata/sql-basics-monsters-using-case/train/sql](http://codewars.com/kata/sql-basics-monsters-using-case/train/sql)

I am trying to solve the question in above link

---

> **INSTRUCTIONS**
>
> You have access to two tables named top_half and bottom_half, as
>   follows:
>
> **top_half schema**
>
> - id
> - heads
> - arms
>
> **bottom_half schema**
>
> - id
> - legs
> - tails
>
> You must return a table with the format as follows:
>
> **output schema**
>
> - id
> - heads
> - legs
> - arms
> - tails
> - species
>
> The IDs on the tables match to make a
>   full monster. For heads, arms, legs and tails you need to draw in the
>   data from each table.
>
> For the species, if the monster has more heads than arms AND/OR more
>   tails than legs, it is a 'BEAST' else it is a 'WEIRDO'. This needs to
>   be captured in the species column.
>
> All rows should be returned (10).
>
> Tests require the use of CASE. Order by species.
>
> Please use pure SQL, only testing is done in Ruby.

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do ? The syntax is wrong after ORDER BY clause. It's hard to guess what is your intention looking at bad code.

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/sql-basics-monsters-using-case/train/sql

Comment: I am trying to solve the question in above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the species, if the monster has more heads than arms AND/OR more
>   tails than legs, it is a 'BEAST' else it is a 'WEIRDO'. This needs to
>   be captured in the species column.

You need to move CASE ... WHEN to the SELECT clause.:

```
select *,
       CASE
          WHEN heads > arms THEN 'beast'
          when tails > legs then 'beast'
          else 'weirdo'
       END    As Species
from top_half 
inner join ....
.....
```

---

> Tests require the use of CASE. Order by species.

Use this clause:

```
....
ORDER BY species
```

or this one:

```
.......
ORDER BY 
       CASE
          WHEN heads > arms THEN 'beast'
          when tails > legs then 'beast'
          else 'weirdo'
       END
```

Answer (score 1):

Consolidated:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN heads > arms OR tails > legs THEN text 'BEAST'
               ELSE 'WEIRDO' END AS species
FORM   top_half 
JOIN   bottom_half USING (id)
ORDER  BY species;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply a question, don´t just place your answer, explain it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.id,t.heads, b.legs,t.arms,b.tails,
CASE 
     WHEN t.heads > t.arms THEN 'BEAST'
     WHEN b.tails > b.legs THEN 'BEAST'
     ELSE  'WEIRDO'

   END as species

from top_half t
join bottom_half b
ON t.id = b.id
ORDER BY species
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply a question, don´t just place your answer, explain it a little bit. In your case edit your question and exposed the Cons and Pros of your answer, as there are another one.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what the code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and more likely to attract upvotes.